# Using Map with read.csv and a pipe delimiter causing errors

Tags: r, file, csv, upload

I am trying to upload a series of text files into a table. Read.csv works on 1 file but when I try and combine files using Map & rbind I get errors I don't understand.
Once I have in a table I can start to clean up the data

I have tried to use lapply but stil get errors just different slightly.

This is the my code so far

> 

```
install.packages(c("readr","dplyr","tidyr","purrr"))
library(readr) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
folder <- "D:/SCANNER/"
files_list <- list.files(path = folder, pattern="*.hmd")
data_wcci<- files_list %>% map(read.csv(header = FALSE,skip="8"))%>%  reduce(rbind)
data_wcci
```

I am hoping to have one table at the end. I keep getting the following error message.

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
 argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

This is a small example of data in text file. Once uploaded I will need to remove \ and and split out into own columns. Remove ; I will also need to use spread on column V1 but haven't thought about code for this yet

```
> data_wcci
                  V1  V2      V3     V4     V5    V6  V7   V8
1            SURVEY\\TTS       11.00         TTS01 FALSE WDM WDM;
2      SECTION\\A3054020     2054.00 270711 270711    NA   ;     
3           OBSERV\\LLRT CR1    0.00    10;           NA         
4              OBVAL\\13       13.20     V;           NA         
5           OBSERV\\LRRT CR1    0.00    10;           NA         
6              OBVAL\\13        3.00     V;           NA         
7           OBSERV\\LLTX CR1    0.00    10;           NA         
8              OBVAL\\13        1.26     V;           NA         
9           OBSERV\\LRTX CR1    0.00    10;           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because your `read.csv` function tries to read the files which are stored in your folder, but you have to provide the full path to read them. You can do this with `paste0(path, list.files[[1]])` for example.

This code snippet should do what you want:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(files_list, function(x) read.csv(paste0(folder, x))))
```